# How can I give priority to a relatively constrained view when both views' heights are defined by their contents?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, interface-builder

I have a [large image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19kdI4LKSjTQhGmA_UbXLx38J1UnWlD12/view?usp=sharing) for an image view and a vertical stack view whose height should be determined by its contents, and the image view's height should scale to match the height of the stack view.

The problem is, because the image is so large, it seems auto layout is giving priority to the image contents over the stack view's contents.  I want the reverse.  I want the priority to be given to the stack view's label contents and I want the imageView's height to adjust accordingly.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="18122" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="18093"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="TestImageStretch" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="mt_fuji" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="mAr-aq-TzN">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="1557"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.99143940210000003" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                            </imageView>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="nSh-Q0-99P">
                                <rect key="frame" x="10" y="54" width="394" height="1503"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="eOa-x3-yuu">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="394" height="1503"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="0.59739550116921769" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <mutableString key="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</mutableString>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <color key="textColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="nSh-Q0-99P" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="00n-kd-6a8"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="nSh-Q0-99P" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="1P5-Uf-OVn"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="mAr-aq-TzN" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="trailing" id="24a-Ml-CeR"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="mAr-aq-TzN" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="top" id="DK7-97-INB"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="nSh-Q0-99P" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="mAr-aq-TzN" secondAttribute="bottom" id="H9X-AQ-Nxv"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="nSh-Q0-99P" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="10" id="Ppl-s2-J3J"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="mAr-aq-TzN" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" id="tME-4k-cft"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-13.043478260869566" y="88.392857142857139"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="mt_fuji" width="2155" height="1557"/>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIImageView` in the storyboard automatically takes up as much size as it's resource image wants (unless you provide explicit `width`/`height` by adding your own constraints).

The problem in your case is - `UIImageView` becomes as tall as it's `UIImage` because you haven't provided any explicit `height` constraint. Now `UIStackView` just follows it's height and it's doing the correct thing.

Here's how you can solve this in storyboard -

1. Wrap your `UIImageView` into a `UIView`.
2. Set it's `top`, `leading` & `trailing` space constraints.
3. Set `Align Bottom Edges` for this `UIView (containing image)` & `UIStackView (containing label)`.

Here's the updated source code for the storyboard -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="18122" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="18093"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="TestImageStretch" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <view clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="CYF-RN-DUQ">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="297.5"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="mt_fuji" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="mAr-aq-TzN">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="1557"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.99143940210000003" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                    </imageView>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="mAr-aq-TzN" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="CYF-RN-DUQ" secondAttribute="leading" id="GmI-gS-DDk"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="mAr-aq-TzN" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="CYF-RN-DUQ" secondAttribute="top" id="WRi-k5-pny"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="mAr-aq-TzN" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="CYF-RN-DUQ" secondAttribute="trailing" id="zUi-Eb-ewz"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="nSh-Q0-99P">
                                <rect key="frame" x="10" y="54" width="394" height="243.5"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="eOa-x3-yuu">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="394" height="243.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="0.59739550116921769" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <mutableString key="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</mutableString>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <color key="textColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="nSh-Q0-99P" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="00n-kd-6a8"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="nSh-Q0-99P" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="1P5-Uf-OVn"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="nSh-Q0-99P" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="CYF-RN-DUQ" secondAttribute="bottom" id="1Se-qO-kq1"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="CYF-RN-DUQ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="top" id="8lt-FC-2c5"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="CYF-RN-DUQ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" id="MBq-ru-P2D"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="nSh-Q0-99P" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="10" id="Ppl-s2-J3J"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="CYF-RN-DUQ" secondAttribute="trailing" id="f9s-bA-wpE"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-13.043478260869566" y="88.392857142857139"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="mt_fuji" width="2155" height="1557"/>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Here's how it looks -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I set the compression resistance of the imageView to be lower than that of the stack view.